# Get every other value of array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, filter

I have an array:

```
Array ( [A] => 4 [B] => 4 [D] => 4 [E] => 8 [F] => 4 [G] => 8 [H] => 8 [J] => 12 [K] => 12 [L] => 11 [M] => 11 [O] => 10 [P] => 10 [Q] => 10 [R] => 10 )
```

It had more values, but I filtered out the zero values, because I don't need them.

Now I need every other value, so that I get:

```
Array ( [A] => 4 [D] => 4 [F] => 4 [H] => 8 [K] => 12 [M] => 11 [P] => 10 [R] => 10 )
```

I also need the remaining array with the keys intact

```
Array ( [B] => 4 [E] => 8 [G] => 8 [J] => 12 [L] => 11 [O] => 10 [Q] => 10 )
```

How can I possibly do this?

The length of the array is subjectible to change. Also the zero values can change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try as

```
$arr = Array ( 'A' => 4, 'B' => 4, 'D' => 4, 'E' => 8, 'F' => 4, 'G' => 8, 'H' => 8, 'J' => 12, 'K' => 12, 'L' => 11, 'M' => 11, 'O' => 10, 'P' => 10, 'Q' => 10, 'R' => 10 );

$arr1 = array();
$arr2 = array();

$i = 0;
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    if($i%2 == 0){
        $arr1[$key] = $value;
    }else{
        $arr2[$key] = $value;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Using `array_walk` function

```
$current = 0;

array_walk($arr,function($v,$k) use(&$result,&$current){
               if($current%2 == 0) {
                   $result['even'][$k] = $v;
               }else{
                   $result['odd'][$k] = $v;
               }
               $current++;
           });
print_r($result);
```

[**Fiddle**](https://eval.in/378943)

[**Fiddle(array_walk)**](https://eval.in/380427)

Comment: Allright... That's pretty easy. I was searching for functions and couldn't find any. Also trying to do something like this, but this is awesome simple! Thanks a lot!